# How do I fix this Swift "decoding could not find key CodingKeys" error?

Tags: json, swift, codable

**I have this JSON:
**

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "dimensions": [],
            "metrics": [
                385,
                54,
                18263,
                120
            ]
        }
    ],
    "previous": null,
    "next": "https://app.tester.com/api/v1/projects/dev-js/tester/query?page=2",
    "page": 1,
    "size": 500,
}
```

**That I need to decode. Currently my STRUT looks like this:
**

```
struct APIRootEA: Codable {
        let results: String?
        let dimensions: String?
        let metrics: String?
        let EAResults: [ResultsEA]
    }
    
    struct ResultsEA: Codable {
        let eaRevenue: Int
        let eaTransactions: Int
        let eaVisits: Int
        let eaActiveUrls: Int
        let previous: String?
        let next: String?
        let page, size: Int
           
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case eaRevenue
            case eaTransactions
            case eaVisits
            case eaActiveUrls
            case previous
            case next
            case page
            case size
           }
       }
```

But i'm getting the error:

could not find key CodingKeys(stringValue: "eaRevenue", intValue: nil) in JSON: No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "eaRevenue", intValue: nil) ("eaRevenue").

The raw data returned from the URLRequest is:

Optional("{"results":[{"dimensions":[],"metrics":[82,289198.5079709999,64782,5218]}],"previous":null,"next":"https://api.tester.com/v1/projects/tester-solutions/tester-project/query?page=2","page":1,"size":500}")

I don't understand why.

I'd appreciate any advice.

I've tried manipulating the STRUT with no success.

Comment: As the error message clearly states, you are trying to decode keys that don't exist in the JSON. There's no `EAResults` key in that JSON at all, so how do you expect to decode it? If you don't know how to decode a JSON response, use [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io) to generate your `Codable` models from the JSON.

Comment: What you should do to start working with this is take each bit of the JSON and point out where that goes to in your struct. Like you have an `Int` called `eaRevenue`. But there is nothing in your JSON even remotely called `eaRevenue` where does that come from? Why is it there? How is it calculated? It seems to come from nowhere. Now, answer those questions around ALL of the properties in your struct. Then you're ready to start writing your decoder for the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a struct that decodes from JSON you should start with at least something that looks like the JSON it is being decoded from.

For instance, in your JSON you have...

```
"metrics": [12, 45, 643, 58],
```

i.e. there is a key `metrics` and it points to an array of integers.

So, to decode this "for free" (i.e. without writing a custom decoder) you should have a struct like...

```
struct MyStruct: Decodable {
  let metrics: [Int]
}
```

If you set `metrics` to anything else it just won't work. (without a custom decoder)

Also, your coding keys is a way to tell Swift what the keys are inside the JSON. Your coding keys contains a key `eaRevenue` but there is no such key in the JSON. This is why you're getting the error you're receiving.

It looks like there is some quite complex logic that you are doing to map from the JSON to the struct. It might be worth starting with something more straight forward and slowly building up to a custom decoder for this behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, I can't read that code inside a comment.